# Status of values generated by OVER and PARTITION BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a source table as follow:

[image]

I want to get the below result:

[image]

**EXPLANATION OF THE SOURCE TABLE:**

This table contains requests with their related tasks on specific dates, each request can have multiple tasks and these tasks can occur many times, I marked each request and it related tasks with different color

For example, the request = 'NC2' in blue has 3 tasks:

1. task1 occurs 3 times over time.
2. task2 occurs 2 times over time.
3. task3 occurs 1 time over time.

**EXPLANATION OF THE RESULT TABLE:**

The score indicates the number of tasks for each request based on time of occurrence.

For example, the request = 'NC2' in blue has 3 tasks:

**SCORE COLUMN:**

task1: first occurrence was on 1/5/2022, then it occurs on 1/7/2022 and lastly on 1/9/2022 "for the same request number"

, as marked on yellow, the same for task two it only occurs twis on 1/6/2022 and 1/8/2022 and for the task3 also.

You can see the score column contains the scores of the tasks based on their occurrence over time for specific request number.

**STATUS COLUMN:**

For the status it shows the first and last occurrence of a task for a specific request, and it ignores the middles like task1 marked in red it's not the first occurrence and neither the last, so it was ignored.

**What I was able to achieve:**

With the query below I was able to get SCORE column:

```
select RequestNumber, Task, StartDate, row_number() over(partition by RequestNumber, TaskName 
order by START_DATE) as score
from [SOURCE_TABLE] order by RequestNumber, START_DATE
```

for the STATUS I am lost, and I couldn't solve it, probably I am thinking inside the box, so any suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly more efficient version of @Larnu's excellent answer:

```sql
SELECT
  RequestNumber,
  Task,
  StartDate,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RequestNumber, TaskName ORDER BY StartDate) AS score,
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER()    OVER (PARTITION BY RequestNumber, TaskName ORDER BY StartDate) = 1
         THEN 'First'
       WHEN LEAD(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY RequestNumber, TaskName ORDER BY StartDate) IS NULL
         THEN 'Last'
       END AS Status
FROM dbo.[SOURCE_TABLE];
```

It uses `LEAD` instead of another `ROW_NUMBER`. This means that the same windowing clause can be used, and therefore does not require another sort, nor a spool.

Comment: Stuff like this makes me look forward to the `WINDOW` clause coming in 2022, as it'll remind me of stuff like this (or rather more likely implicitly have ,e use it, due to me using the `WINDOW` clause and defining the window once).

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to use a `CASE` expression on the value of `score`. As you'd need to check if the value of `Score` was the `MAX` value, then you'll need to use a CTE for this, like so:

```sql
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT RequestNumber,
            Task,
            StartDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RequestNumber, TaskName ORDER BY START_DATE) AS score
     FROM dbo.[SOURCE_TABLE])
SELECT RequestNumber,
       Task,
       StartDate,
       score,
       CASE score WHEN 1 THEN 'First'
                  WHEN MAX(score) OVER (PARTITION BY RequestNumber, TaskName) THEN 'Last'
       END AS Status
FROM CTE
ORDER BY RequestNumber,
         START_DATE;
```

Alternatively you could use `ROW_NUMBER` again, but in the opposite direction, and the you wouldn't need the CTE:

```sql
SELECT RequestNumber,
       Task,
       StartDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RequestNumber, TaskName ORDER BY START_DATE) AS score,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RequestNumber, TaskName ORDER BY START_DATE) = 1 THEN 'First'
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RequestNumber, TaskName ORDER BY START_DATE DESC) = 1 THEN 'Last'
       END AS Status
FROM dbo.[SOURCE_TABLE];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close, I'd go for something like

```
SELECT
     RequestNumber
    ,Task
    ,StartDate
    ,AscRowNo AS Score
    ,CASE
        WHEN AscRowNo = 1 AND DescRowNo = 1 THEN '???'
        WHEN AscRowNo = 1 THEN 'First'
        WHEN DescRowNo = 1 THEN 'Last'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Status
FROM (
    SELECT
         RequestNumber
        ,Task
        ,StartDate
        ,row_number() over(partition by RequestNumber, TaskName order by START_DATE) as AscRowNo
        ,row_number() over(partition by RequestNumber, TaskName order by START_DATE DESC) as DescRowNo
    from [SOURCE_TABLE]
) as x
ORDER BY
    RequestNumber,
    START_DATE
```

The two ROW_Numbers will identify the first and last occurrence of a task.

Note: what if there is only one occurrence globally? is it first or last?

Comment: basically the same suggested by @Larnu but he is way faster than me at answering

Comment: Side note, the `ELSE NULL` is kinda of redundant. If none of the `CASE` expression's `WHEN` clauses resolve to TRUE, then `NULL` is returned anyway, even if there isn't an `ELSE`.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I wrote it anyway to make it explicit (in case he wants to handle "middle rows" differently)